# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'verified_email'

Tags: python, flask, decorator, attributeerror

I am trying to create a decorator function, which checks if user's email is verified, but I am getting this error.

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'verified_email'**

Does somebody know how to solve it?

```
def email_verified(func):
    def check_verification():
        user = current_user
        if user.verified_email == True:
            return func()
        else:
            flash("verify your email")
            return redirect(url_for(index))
    return check_verification()
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition needs the current_user as some kind of input.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a check like this

```py
...
        if user and user.verified_email:
            return func()
        else:
...
```